# pyral create userstory gives error pyral.restapi.RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Could not read: Object not found for Object ID: null

Tags: rally, put

I am trying to create a user story in rally using pyral. I get the following error

> File "rally-post.py", line 46, in 
>       task = rally.put('UserStory', info)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyral/restapi.py", line 1024, in put
>       raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem)
>   pyral.restapi.RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Could not read: Object not found for Object ID: null

```
info = { "Workspace"   : workspace,
         "Project"     : project,
         "Name"        : name,
         "Description" : description,
         "Owner"       : _owner,
         "SCHEDULE STATE" : "Defined",
         "STORY TYPE"  : "New Feature"}

user_story = rally.put('UserStory', info)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably due to the workspace and project variables.  Are you passing the Name of the Workspace and Project?  It is expecting the Reference to both.

Also, you will run into two more issues with your "SCHEDULE STATE" and "STORY TYPE".  I am assuming "STORY TYPE" is a Custom Field of type String. 
 There should not be any spaces in the field names.

The updated 'info' below should help.  I left in the References to Workspace, Project and Owner so you can see what it is expecting.

```
info = { "Workspace" : "/workspace/123456",
         "Project" : "/project/123456",
         "Name" : name,
         "Description" : description,
         "Owner" : "/user/123456",
         "ScheduleState" : "Defined",
         "StoryType" : "New Feature"
        }
```